# Angular resource service does not consume rest ful service in rails (Json format)

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m developing a web application where I have a front-end built with AngularJS that consumes Rest Services provided by a back-end API Rails application.

I would like to use the Angular $resource to get the Json objects in the backend API.

Client and Server applications run in different servers so far. So, angular client is in server-path:1234/app and backend api application runs in another-server-path:3000/.

Where server-path and another-server-path are localhost.

Both sides are developed, and works independently. I mean:

1. When I run another-server-path:3000/boats in a browser I get the list of boats, so the Restful service looks to be working.
2. I did a simulation in the client side, so, in my service I replaced the real url with a simulated url to a json data source. This code works too.

Now, I want to call the backend restful service in another-server-path:3000/boats from the angular service, but it´s now showing any data, neither I can see any get request in servers logs.

This is my angular service code:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
//  value('version', '0.1');

factory('Boat', function($resource){
    return $resource('another-server-path:3000/:boatId', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{boatId:'boats'}, isArray:true}
  });
```

});

and this is my backend rails controller:

```
def index
  @boats = Boat.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @boats}
    format.json { render :json => @boats}
  end
end
```

What am I missing? Please help.

**UPDATE:**
In Angular app, I changed my service file with:

```
return $resource('another-server-path\\:3000/:boatId', {}, {
query: {method:'GET', params:{boatId:'boats'}, isArray:true}
```

I also added this line to my app.js file:

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
```

and now I got the request in the api server. The controller is also executed. I got the boats from the DB. However I´m not able to send them back in JSON to Angular.

This is my api Controller:

```
def index
  @boats = Boat.all
  puts @boats
  render :json => @boats          
end
```

and this is the log I got when it´s called:

```
    Started GET "/boats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-26 17:05:49 +0200
Processing by BoatsController#index as HTML
  Boat Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `boats`.* FROM `boats`
#<Boat:0x0000000675d9f0>
#<Boat:0x000000089e74a8>
#<Boat:0x000000089e71b0>
#<Boat:0x000000089e6e40>
Completed 200 OK in 66ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

As you can see, first, it says it is been processed as HTML instead of JSON. An second it is not sent to Angular back.

Comment: This could be a cross domain request issue. If the site which is making the request is different from the server then it is a cross domain call. Google for how to achieve it using angularjs.

Comment: Are you using version 1.0.x of angularJS? In that case you need to escape the port on url: `$resource('another-server-path\\:3000/:boatId'`

Comment: I changed the url to return $resource('http\\://localhost\\:3000/:boatId', {}, {
     query: {method:'GET', params:{boatId:'boats'}, isArray:true}   . Now, It looks like I reached the api server, I can see a new trace, trying to request something, however it´s an error trace: Started OPTIONS "/boats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-26 08:40:21 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/boats"):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working!

I configure my Rails api to accept cross-domain request by putting this configuration in config/application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
}
```

my service file with the resource call:

```
factory('Boat', function($resource){    
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1\\:3000/:boatId', {}, {       
    query: {method:'GET', params:{boatId:'boats'}, isArray:true}
  });
}).
```

and my Rails API controller:

```
def index

  @boats = Boat.all
  puts @boats
  render :json => @boats          
end
```

It looks easy, but this combination took me three days.